# Inner product with matrix intuition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

I am working on a paper where some objects appears quiet frequently. I feel like they have a deeper meaning which can be explained but I don't have the intuition to understand them. I'm hoping that someone here can help.

Let $\eta \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a unit vector and $H$ a positive definite matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ (The Hessian matrix of a convex function, to be more precise).

Then, the objects I am trying to understand are:
$\langle \eta, H \eta \rangle$ and $\langle \eta, H^{-1} \eta \rangle$.
I would be glad about every bit of gained intuition. Thank you very much!

Comment: Perhaps try searching up quadratic forms.

Comment: In general: (1): $\langle U,V \rangle$ is identifiable with (2): $U^TV$ where $U,V$ are column vectors with respect to a same reference basis. (1) is called an intrinsic notation, whereas (2) is an extrinsic (base dependent) one.

Comment: Therefore $\langle \eta, H \eta \rangle$ is identifiable with $\eta^T H \eta$ and it is under this form that you will meet quadratic forms in all "practically oriented" presentations of linear algebra.

Comment: Another search term to start with may be "Positive definite"; You will immediately run into your bit of notation as interpreted by Jean Marie.

Comment: @m Perhaps this is helpful: if $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ has gradient $\nabla f$ and Hessian $H$, then the second-order Taylor series expansion of $f$ at $x$ is given by
$$
f(x + \eta) = f(x) + \langle \nabla f(x), \eta \rangle + \frac 12 \langle \eta,H(x)\eta \rangle + o(\|\eta\|^2)
$$